# Detect how action.MAIN was called in a home launcher app

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen, android-launcher

I'm working on a home launcher app, using two fragments within the main activity, one fragment displays the "home screen" and the other displays the "app drawer".

On returning to the launcher from another app using either the (softkey/hardkey) back or home keys, the intent `android.intent.action.MAIN` is called.

Is there anyway to tell the difference between the launcher being brought back to the front using the back key, to using the home key, so that the event can be handled individually?

*My intention is to keep the app drawer open (fragment two) if returning to the launcher using the back key, and to show the "home screen" (fragment one) if returning using the home key.*

Extra: the activity uses the launch mode: singleTask